# Opacity filter in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, internet-explorer-8

I need to create a fadein method for learning purpose. I read on SO somewhere that an element needs to have certain height and width for the IE8 to render opacity properly. The element on which I am trying to use opacity, has an layout, has width and height, and even then it is not working. 
I found a workaround to use opacity somehow using filters. 
It does works but it also messes up my layout.

My code for opacity is :

```
var e = document.getElementById("nav");
e.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + .5 * 100 + ')';
```

And code for nav css

```
#nav                    
{
    /*top: -10px;       
    height: 55px;    
    display: block;
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%;        
    background: #fff;   

}
```

Now, if I comment out these lines the page rendered is like
[image: Id I comment out the above jScript Line]

Now, when these lines are allowed to execute, the page is like[image: Opacity is there. But....]

I have used relative positioning for navigation menu and moved it up a little bit using top.
Please suggest me what is the problem?

Comment: Another problem with IE... I think microsoft would do the world a favor to remove it from being produced.

Comment: @TheWobbuffet I agree with you.

Comment: For testing purposes, put a border on your nav element.  I suspect it doesn't have the size / shape you believe it does.  Additionally, for things like this I **strongly** recommend jQuery.  Removes all cross-browser challenges, and makes things like fading in/out trivial: `$('#nav').fadeIn();` - (literally, that's all it takes).

Comment: I can't move to IE9 or IE10.
I am supposed to do it on IE8.

Comment: @TheWobbuffet — A problem with the no-longer-supported IE8. IE11 is a decent browser.

Comment: I have added the CSS for div "nav".
I have mentioned height and width.
@cale_b: Do i still need to add border ?